# If only one object is created during inheritance then what is super keyword referencing to?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, super

In the following code, what is super keyword referencing to?

```
class A {
    int i1 = 10;
    A() {
        System.out.println("class A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    int i2 = super.i1;
    B() {
        System.out.println("class B");
    }
}
class C extends B {
    int i3 = super.i2;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println(c.i3);
    }
}
```

If no objects/instances of super class are created, then what is super keyword referencing to as it is a reference variable and supposed to reference super class instance?

Comment: there is just one object, but it is a C, as well as it is a B, as well as it is an A. super(); calls the constructor of the parent class

Comment: It makes no sense. I mean, people often write it for convention, but it has no effects in the A class.

Comment: i doubt you need super here. you can remove super and get same result.

Comment: If you don't write `super()` here, the compiler inserts it for you [as described here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7), because the superclasses have zero-arg constructors.

Comment: @ArnauMas it has no real "effect" in the other classes, neither

Comment: @Stultuske yes, it would print "class B" and "class A", since you would be calling the parents constructors. Although you don't need to make it explicit, because the compiler does it anyways.

Comment: @ArnauMas which is what I meant by "no effect". if you don't explicitly add it, it still executes. The same is done for the one in the A class. If you think that super() call there (whether explicit or implicit) is not important, I think you're missing the obvious

Comment: @Stultuske so if there is no instance of A or B class, super() is calling super class constructor directly from the class loaded during runtime?

Comment: an instance of C IS an instance of B and of A, that's the whole inheritance thing

Comment: I meant object. Let me rephrase my question: So if there is no object of A or B class, super() is calling super class constructor directly from the class loaded during runtime?

Comment: @mp3001 Correct. When you creat a new C, B and A are created too (whether you make it explicit with super() or not), because they need to exist in order to create C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `super` is a bit different from `this`, in that `super` is not a *primary expression*. In fact, `super` is not an expression at all. So it makes little sense to say that `super` itself *refers* to anything. Note that you can't do:

```
SomeType foo = super;
```

What *does* make sense, are these (not an exhaustive list of everything that involves `super`):

- superclass constructor calls of the form `super(...);`
- field access of the form `super.identifier`
- method call of the form `super.identifier(...)`

*Those forms* all refer to different things, but the word `super` itself has no single meaning, unless you are satisfied with "something to do with the superclass".

Specifically in this question, you are asking about field access. This is described in section [15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2) of the language specification.

> The form `super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of the current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class.

For `i1`, since `B` inherits from `A`, `i1` will refer to the same field even if you view the current object as a `B`, so it doesn't matter what class you view the current object as. Whether it is `super.i1`, or `this.i1`, or just `i1`, doesn't make a difference. The difference is more apparent when you *redeclare* `i1` in `B`:

```
class A { 
    int i1 = 10;
}
class B extends A { 
    int i1 = 20; 
    int i2 = super.i1;
}
```

`i2` will get the value of 10, rather than `20`, because you viewed the current object as an `A`. Note that in this case, an instance of `B` gets two fields called `i1`, one inherited from `A`, and one declared in `B`. Viewing the object "as an `A`" will let you see the one inherited from `A`, otherwise it is hidden.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Just one question, if there no objects of A and B and constructor is not inherited then from where is super() calling constructor from?

Comment: So the instances of A and B are created only because of call to each of their super constructors? And like you said these instances(of A and B) are actually the instance/object of C class just viewed as instances of A and B, right?

Comment: @mp3001 I think my last comment might have confused you. What I meant was, if you did `new B()` (let's deal with one level of inheritance first, just so it's easier to explain), then there is an instance of `B`. If `B`'s constructor then calls `super()` (which it does implicitly), no new objects are created, and the constructor body of `A` is simply executed. And I think your confusion is this: how can the constructor body of `A` be run, when there are no `A` objects? Well, the truth is, we do have a `B` object, and because of inheritance, a `B` object ***is a*** `A` object.

Comment: @mp3001 I didn't say anything about instances of `B` being "viewed as" instances of `A` here. That part of my answer is about _field access_ of the form `super.Identifier`, not about constructor calls. I don't even know what "viewed as instances of `A`" would mean in the context of constructor calls.

Comment: Ok correct me where I'm wrong, an instance of B is also an instance of A because of inheritance. And in case references of B type and A type refer to the same object, say ``B b = new B(); C c = b;`` then they have same fields and methods, only difference being when it comes to two classes having same field defined differently. In that case, instances referred by b and c has their own copy of that field.

Comment: `B b = new B(); C c = b;` won't even compile, and it's not clear what you mean by "only difference being when it comes to two classes having same field defined differently". What fields are you talking about? _Name_ them, please. @mp3001

Comment: Sorry, I meant ``B b = new B(); A a = b;``.

Comment: Here is how I understand it. An instance of B is also an instance of A because of inheritance. And in case references of B type and A type refer to the same object of class B, say ``B b = new B(); A a = b;`` then they have same fields and methods, only difference being when it comes to two classes having same field defined differently. In that case, instances referred by b and c has their own copy of that field.(The field I'm referring to is ``i1`` in the example provided by you)

Comment: Thanks. And yes it was meant to be a not c. Now one last thing, during object creation ``new B()`` super() is executed implicitly in B's constructor, which calls A's constructor. Only thing I want to know is from where is A's constructor code being executed as it is not inherited?

Comment: @mp3001 You can always access the superclass constructor in the first statement of a constructor declaration. The bytecode of `A` is available to the JVM, so of course it is possible to be run. As another example, the superclass implementations of overridden methods are also not inherited, but you can still call them with `super.foo()`. It works the same way: the JVM knows where to find the superclass' code. Anyway, note constructors are quite special. They are not even _members_. There are quite a few special cases regarding them.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int i2 = super.i1; and int i2 = i1; both are same
```

as i1 gets inherited from parent class A to child class B
Like wise

```
int i3 = super.i2;  and int i3 = i2; both are same
```

Super only refers to Parent class.
When you created object of class C ,One object is created - an instance of C.

C is additionally and simultaneously an instance of B and an instance of A and also Object
Since C is simultaneously an instance of B and an instance of A that's why a cal super() is added in the constructor to call the constructor of the parent class C's constructor call B's constructor and B's constructor calls A's constructor

Comment: If there is no object of super class, is super() calling constructor of super class from the loaded class by JVM?

Comment: Yes super() just calls the constructor of parent class to make sure all the inherited member variables of parent class are properly initiallized

Comment: @mp3001 Yes, just running the code for the superclass constructor doesn't require an instance of the superclass. It can do it with an instance of the subclass too, which it does have.